# Update magic file list and/or submit my own

Tags: linux

I love `file`. I use it multiple times a day. I love it so much that I install Cygwin on my Windows machines just so I can use it. Anyway, in going through older files on my system, I find there are many files that just report "data" from the `file` command. Understandably.

Some of these files however do have an indicator in their header of what kind of file they are, but are not found in the magic file database yet. My questions are three-fold:

1. Is there an online repository of magic file definitions that I can use to supplement or update the default ones that came with my OS? (My folder /usr/share/file/magic shows the most recent entry as almost one year ago, and I know people are continually updating these definitions)
2. How can I submit a new definition that I've developed so that the rest of the *nix community can benefit? The online repo?
3. Is it as simple as dropping the magic definition file in the folder, and my OS will magically find it, or do I have to somehow rebuild the definition library? Do I have to do anything with the magic.mgc file, or just the folder of individual definitions?

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: `file` is fully scriptable - you can put your own magic tests in script files and specify these on the command line with `-[mM]` switches. See the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html).

Comment: To answer question #3, it seems like compiling your own definitions is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7236191/695772

Comment: After testing my magic file, I tried `file -C -m myfile` and it produced `myfile.mgc` and `magic.mgc`. I tried copying these files to `~/.magic`, and `/usr/share/file/magic`. When I re-run the `file` command on my file, it still reads "data". How can I tell the system to use my new definition?

Comment: @tralston You should've copied the compiled version to `~/.magic.mgc` not to `~/.magic`; or simply copied the `myfile` text definition to `~/.magic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I've had changes included in the `magic` file by submitting a Debian bug report but it's probably faster to submit them upstream directly.

In answer to your questions:

1. The latest released source can be found [here](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) - there's a link to [a mirror](https://github.com/file/file) of the source repo there.
2. Yes, I believe either submitting a bug report or emailing the mailing list should be all that's needed to add a file definition.
3. You can create your own `magic` file and point `file` file to it by using the `-m` option.

Comment: 1.) I actually found that a little while ago too. But how do I update my system with the latest repo? Should I just checkout the repo and copy the files to my system? Or is there an apt-get way of pulling the repo?
3.) Is there a way to do it such that I don't have to always include the `-m` argument? That's what I mean in the question comments by it compiling but not recognizing my new definition.

Comment: As noted [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213611/update-magic-file-list-and-or-submit-my-own#comment932868_213611) copy the the magic file to `~/.magic` and/or the magic database to `~/.magic.mgc` and your magic file should be picked up without having to supply the `-m` parameter. That is _unless_ you are running [macOS Catalina](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154001/file1-and-magic5-describing-other-formats#comment1371638_505314) (or possibly some other macOS release).

Comment: Regarding the question of getting the newest release of the magic files: I'm not sure if this is such a good idea because the syntax of the magic files might change between releases (at least the format of the database can be incompatible) so it might be better to grab the complete release instead just the magic files considering that releases are [rather frequent](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/ChangeLog).

Answer (score 2):

About your question 3. :

Try adding your custom definitions to `/etc/magic`. It will be used alongside the pre-compiled `magic.mgc` file.

If it doesn't work, check with

```
file --version
```

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, it reports:

> ```
> file-5.25
> magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
> ```

So it uses both the `/etc/magic` text file, and the pre-compiled `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc` file